# Azure AD - Getting list of users from multiple AAD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I'm building a Web application that will have multiple users. These users will be administrators from a company. Each company will have different Azure AD.

I'm trying to find a way to allow my Web application to connect to the different AAD so that it could pull users into a list every time I visit a screen called "Select a user from your organisation".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the users from Azure AD we can use the Azure AD Graph. And we need to get the access token before we can use the Azure AD Graph. First we need to register an web app from [Azure Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/). And to enable the multiple company administrators use it we need to enable the multi-tenant.

I also wrote a [demo project](https://github.com/VitorX/AzureADSamples) to list the users for the tenant who sign-in. You can refer it like figure below.
[image]

And you also can find a lot of samples about Azure AD from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-code-samples/).